# The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData in TabItem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am having an issue in tabitem, if i put ImageIcon then it shows an error "The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'." How to fix this issue because i want to add custom image icon?

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
final List<TabItem> tabs = [
    TabItem(
      tabName: "Home",
      icon: ImageIcon(
  AssetImage('images/event.png'), // On this line getting an error
  ),
      page: HomePage(),
    ),];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. try `Image.asset()` for this

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/1.png',//just change my image with your image
            height: 30,
          ),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Problem is i'm using TabItem and if i use your code which is BottomNavigationBarItem then it gives lot of errors from my side.

Comment: I just want to use custom icons inside tabitem instead of inbuild icon.

Comment: BottomNavigation BottomNavigation({required void Function(int) onSelectTab, required List  tabs})